# Attempting to suggest an edit while the suggested edit queue is full using the "Edit" button within a review task fails silently

Tags: bug, review, edits, error-message

I'm reviewing [this First answers item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34108275) and I attempted to edit it, but the suggested edit queue is full.

I prefer to use the "Edit" menu button as opposed to the "Edit" review action, so that I can take further action if necessary (such as voting, etc). Clicking this edit button fails silently, and doesn't display the "The suggested edit queue is full" error message that I would ordinarily expect.

Here's a GIF demonstration where I also attempt to use the "Edit" review action to indicate that the suggested edit queue is, indeed, full:

[image: Gif of me attempting to click the Edit menu option on a review item and being stopped despite not seeing an error message]

I know you can't really see me clicking the Edit button towards the beginning of the GIF, but you'll just have to trust me that I am actually clicking it.

In this situation, I'd expect to see the error message one normally gets when attempting to submit a suggested edit when the queue is full:

[image: Image of me seeing the suggested edit queue is full error message normally, outside of a review]

Could this be looked into and fixed?